# Should I ask to extend my internship/for a full-time offer if I only plan on being with the company for 1 year?

Tags: professionalism, career-development, internship, professional-development

I am starting an MS program in Human-Computer Interaction this upcoming fall on the west coast and am currently interning as a UX Design intern on the east coast this summer. The company is mid-sized and growing.

I’m loving the team I’m working with and the projects and work they do (the industry that the company is in is one I’m particularly passionate about). A couple of the designers on the team work from the west coast. I was considering asking my manager about the possibility of extending my internship or becoming a remote employee while I go to school (my master’s program allows part-time students, so I can go part-time IF need be).

The issue is, it is a goal to obtain a summer internship next summer for a company like Google, Microsoft, Amazon, etc. My university also has strong business and alumni connections to a lot of these big companies.

If I only plan on being with this current company for a year, is there a way to ask about the opportunity to continue working for them past the end of this summer? If I’m not able to land any of those internships, it’d be nice to still be able to work for this company.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ask them for a full time job, see what they think of the idea. If you get the job then it's all good, keep it until you land an internship next summer. Do **not** quit this job until you're certain you're being accepted into one of the big companies.

There is a lot of competition for companies like Google, Microsoft and Amazon so be mindful when it comes to applying, having this job may be extremely good for you as a backup at the least.

Don't mention that you're going to leave after a year, wait till it's guaranteed then hand in your notice when you're ready and it lines up with the time periods, then you can tell them the reason.